# Create SQL Developer procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

I have following database

- Customer (customerNO, customerName, address, city, category, custBalance)
- Product (productNO, label, price, QStock)
- CustomerOrder (orderNO, orderDate, #customerNO)
- OrderedProduct (#orderNO, #productNO , orderQuantity )

and want to create these programs

First one is: a stored function called `productPerOrder` to return the number of products placed for any order its number is given as input.

Second one: a trigger called `changeCustomer_Category` which should be invoked before any update of customer balance in customer table. Its job is to modify the category of a customer from B2 to B1 and from C2 to C1 when a customer's balance status drops below a certain threshold (-10000).

Comment: If you run into problems you can ask a specific question here.

Comment: what is your question? what have you attempted to do on your own?

Comment: i want the sql for Trigger and Function

Comment: @halatech it's your job to write that code, and then come back here when you have code specific problems, then it's OUR job to help you answer those questions. It's not our job to write that code for you.

Comment: Welcome to the SO Community. The community will help you with your issues, but it has certain expectations of you and **it is not a code writing service**.  You need to spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. In particular you need to post complete table description (ddl), sample data, expected results for that data and *what you have written so far*. All as text - **no images**.

Comment: @halatech it's not a "SQL Developer procedure". SQL Developer is just one development tool for Oracle out there. You could create the same procedure in PL/SQL Developer or Toad or SQL\*Plus etc.

Comment: As others have commented, this isn't a question to help you with an specific problem, seems like a question to do your work, so you better start creating your own funcion or trigger, and once you stumble into errors in your code, come here to ask questions about the errors you encounter or the undesired results you are getting with your code.